# Almacenamiento de datos en una variable desde un array con javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy hace rato atrapado con algo, tengo un array donde estoy almacenando datos desde una api, dentro de un for, también tengo una variable donde los datos del array quiero que queden almacenados como si fuera un diccionario, pero al imprimir por consola solo me imprime como [object object] [object object], espero puedan ayudarme mi codigo es el siguiente:

y por consola me arroja esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero yo necesito que me imprima por consola de la siguiente manera dentro de la variable (calEvents) que almaceno el arreglo del for:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 var datos = [];
   var calEvents = [];
   var idvisita = 0;

   //Al iniciar el documento, disparamos la funcion
   $$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

       //Definimos una variable con la url de datos.
       var url = 'http://localhost:xxxxx';//LOCAL
       $$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

         for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            datos = [
            
               {

                  'from': new Date('"' + data[i].fecha_visita + '"'),
                  'to': new Date('"' + data[i].fecha_visita + '"'),

               },

            ];

            calEvents += JSON.stringify(datos);

         }//Fin for

         console.log(calEvents);

         var calendarInline = app.calendar ({

            container: '#calendar-inline-container',
            value: [new Date()],
            weekHeader: false,
            events: calEvents
            });
});
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías compartir el código como un fragmento de código en lugar de una imagen?

Comment: Basicamente += convierte el array en string, lo que necesitas es un concat o push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si `calEvents` es un array debes hacer un `push`, ademas ser solo objetos y no un array con un solo indice

```
datos = {
    from: new Date('"' + data[i].fecha_visita + '"'),
    to: new Date('"' + data[i].fecha_visita + '"'),
};
calEvents.push(datos);
```

Comment: funciono como mencionaste, y el problema que yo tenia era que el codifgo lo tenia con corchetes  datos = [{
    from: new Date('"' + data[i].fecha_visita + '"'),
    to: new Date('"' + data[i].fecha_visita + '"'),
},];

Comment: Si, @David, me parece que basta con que sean objetos y todos queden en el array de calEvents, Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Como se mencionó en un comentario el operador `+=` realiza una suma o una concatenación dependiendo si los objetos valores se pueden interpretar como número o cadena de texto.

Para agregar un elemento un objeto tipo Array debes hacerlo de otra forma

- Array.prototype.push (ejemplo `miArray.push('miValor'`)
- indices ( ejemplo `miArray[1] = 'mi valor'`)

En lugar de `'miValor`' puedes incluir un objeto del tipo `{mipropiead:'miValor'}` para que se muestre en la consola ya que objetos de tipos complejos no se mostrarán como `[object object]`

Comment: @David Que atento, pero no hace falta publicar comentarios para dar las gracias, aquí lo que esperamos que se haga para mostrar el agradecimiento es votar las publicaciones  Más detalles en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ahh pero no se puede dar ni las gracias por la ayuda? Aparte miArray[1] === 'mi valor' es una comprobación no una asignación

Comment: @EugeniBejan No se debería publicar comentarios cuya única finalidad es agradecer eso se explica en el enlace que dejé en mi comentario previo, si vas a decir algo más, si lo deseas puedes agregar el "gracias" de paso. Por cierto, gracias por la observación, ya corregí mi respuesta.

Comment: Okei, no hay de que.

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en que al utilizar += javascript convertira el `array` a string

Por ejemplo si intentamos hacer lo siguiente:

1. Convertir un array que simplemente contenga numeros a cadena de texto.

```js
let num = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(num.toString())
```

Como vemos que el resultado son los datos del array convertidos en un text.

Ahora veamos que pasa si hacemos lo mismo para un objeto.

```js
let a = {name:'Nombre'}
console.log(a.toString())
```

Aquí el resultado es un `[object Object]`

Entonces sabiendo esto, nos da por pensar de que el operador += no nos sirve para arrays.

Para eso podemos utilziar los metodos push o concat.

Ejemplo:

```js
let calEvents = []

for(let i =0; i< 10; i++) {
  let datos = [{
    name:i
  }]
  calEvents.push(datos)
}

console.log(calEvents)
```

> Si utilizas concat tienes que asignarlo a si mismo: datos= datos.concat(array)

Comment: @David Selecciona la respuesta que te haya servido y haya solucionado el problema y aceptala. mira el [tour] nuevamente